# Pixels in photoshop vs pixels in CSS?

Tags: css, photoshop

I notice that when I measure out something in Photoshop to "ensure pixel perfection" it's usually half of what's measured in Photoshop to go to CSS. So if I measure at 60px, in CSS it goes to 30px.

But only roughly so.. Is there a way to make sure it matches 100% so I don't have to guesstimate? And why does this happen?

Comment: It shouldn't... how are you measuring pixels in Photoshop?

Comment: @Orbling By using the marquee tool, and setting the units to pixels. There's also the 'info' window which shows the same data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are measuring out those pixels in Photoshop, you have to make sure you know what size your resolution is. For the web, it uses 72 dpi resolution, check in Photoshop under "image size" to see what resolution your image is. Sometimes images are at 300 dpi which if you use that and then try to save on the web will make the image larger than it should be.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've checked DPI and I see this: http://d.pr/i/ePqA, shouldn't everything match up then?

Answer (score 0):

In Photoshop:
Ctrl + N > Web tab > Web Most Common
This Artboard will set the settings to be fir for webpages. Now screenshots from the browser should match the PS pixels values.

Also make sure that your browser settings haven't changed the zoom ratio or font size.