# Size in pixels in photoshop differ from CSS

Tags: html, css, photoshop, dpi

Firstly I want you to know about [DPI / Resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRC2A.png) of mine layout.

I have a layout in photoshop using which I am coding. So when I try to set the number of pixels at margin-left it differs from that, which set in PSD layout.
[Here is a screenshot from that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKWT5.png)

But when I set the same properties at my .css file

```
.header__logo {
  margin-top: 52px;
  margin-left: 300px; <- Expected size
  display: flex;
}
```

The result differs. Note, that my PSD project has got 72 DPI / Resolution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pixels in photoshop vs pixels in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885035/pixels-in-photoshop-vs-pixels-in-css)

Comment: I looked at this question, and it was indicated there that the problem is in DPI.